# Uncaught Reference Error : JQuery is not Defined at drupal.js

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

When clearing the Drupal Cache it automatically enable/ checks the Compressed the cache pages options and breaks many drupal functionality.

when i inspect i found that JQuery is not Defined at drupal.js at line 5 [jQuery.noconflict() ]. i find this error on all the pages of drupal.

I am not sure what have caused this error.

Comment: Probably the Jquery script is not loaded or loaded after drupal.js

Comment: What should i do to make it work ? want more info how to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: As you mentioned the Jquery script is loading after drupal.js, How do i change it.

Comment: How are you including the js? Have a look at the [the documentation here](https://www.drupal.org/node/756722), you should be able to use the *weight* property to change the loading order.

Comment: I've done accordingly,  but also i still see the error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Login in your drupal site as admin and access here:

/admin/config/development/jquery_update

Can you check the jquery version on the "Default jquery version" field. Change it to 1.10.

Comment: It mentioned as the same. Default Jquery version - 1.10. Is there something else that should be updated ? l

Comment: Well, it must be a js weight problem, so, do this: 

- Check if you are using the drupal_add_js function in any  custom theme or custom  module and if you are and you are using the "weigth" option, read the following post: https://www.drupal.org/node/756722